# sql verify relationship over two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables: A and B

Table A columns:
content_key
data_key

Table B columns:
content_key
person_key

I need to verify that for each data_key there is only one person_key that is associated with it, it can have the same person_key multiple times but only one unique value.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` the `data_key` and `person_key`

```
SELECT count(data_key) cnt, data_key, person_key
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b
    ON a.content_key = b.content_key
GROUP BY data_key, person_key
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is with COUNT(DISTINCT):

```
select A.data_key, count(distinct person_key) as numPersons
from A join
     B
     on A.content_key = B.content_key
group by A.data_key
order by 2 desc
```

I added the order by, so you can see the duplicates first.

Well, since you want to verify rather than see the duplicates, add a HAVING clause:

```
having count(distinct person_key) > 1
```

If the query returns no rows, then the data meets your condition.

Also, this assumes that person_key is never NULL.  The count is a bit more complicated if that can happen:

```
(COUNT(distinct person_key) + max(case when person_key is null then 1 else 0 end))
```